# What is the recommended approach to implement SQL session state since ASP.NET Identity was released?

Tags: asp.net, sql-session-state

These are the options I am aware of:

**ASP.NET Universal Providers:**
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Providers

I have used this in the past for SQL Azure and on premise SQL Server is supported. However in this case I won't be using Membership, Roles etc. which have been superseded by ASP.NET identity. Not sure it makes sense to install this old Nuget package to get sessions.

**Using Aspnet_regsql.exe:**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

**Running InstallSqlState.sql:**
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317604

(Looks a little dated)

**ASP.NET Session State using SQL Server In-Memory:**
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kenkilty/2014/07/03/asp-net-session-state-using-sql-server-in-memory/

Looks promising but not sure it's got much traction? We're on SQL 2012 and would have to find out about upgrading to SQL 2014.

Comment: Links that were deleted due to insufficient reputation:

**Using Aspnet_regsql.exe:**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

**Running InstallSqlState.sql:**

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317604

**ASP.NET Session State using SQL Server In-Memory:**

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kenkilty/2014/07/03/asp-net-session-state-using-sql-server-in-memory

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you using and are you using ASP.NET Web Forms or ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: @BrianOgden I'm using ASP.NET 4.6 and MVC 5 (5.2.3).